# Datagridview filter from textbox

Tags: vb.net

i have a vb.net datagridiew and i fill my datagridview add manuel rows

I read too many questions about this questions and answers, but i could't find my answer.

```
  Dim I = .Rows.Add
 .Rows(I).Cells(0).Value = "AA"
```

for example;

```
COLUMN1  COLUMN2
AA        1
BB        2
```

so i want filter datagridview from textbox1.text change

What i tried;

```
TryCast(dgv1.DataSource, DataTable).DefaultView.RowFilter = "COLUMN1 LIKE '%A%'"
```

Answer (score 1):

Implementation as per comment by @Jimi

```
Private Sub Form1_Load(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles MyBase.Load
    BindGrid()
End Sub

Private Sub BindGrid()
    Dim dt As New DataTable
    dt.Columns.Add("Column1", GetType(String))
    dt.Columns.Add("Column2", GetType(Integer))
    DataGridView1.DataSource = dt
End Sub

Private Sub Button1_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Button1.Click
    TryCast(DataGridView1.DataSource, DataTable).DefaultView.RowFilter = "COLUMN1 LIKE '%A%'"
End Sub
```

Comment: Rather than messing with the `DataSource`, you should add a `BindingSource` in the designer, bind the `DataTable` to the `BindingSource` and the `BindingSource` to the grid, then simply set the `Filter` of the `BindingSource`.

Comment: Also, the way you're using `TryCast` there is wrong. It will work but it's still wrong. The whole point of `TryCast` is that it will return `Nothing` if the cast fails, where `DirectCast` will throw an exception. Your code is assuming that the cast has succeeded and uses the result directly, which would throw a `NullReferenceException` if it failed. If you are using `TryCast` because the cast might fail then you should be testing for `Nothing` before using the result. If you know it won't fail then you should be using `DirectCast`.

Answer (score 0):

Create a class which represents a single row.

```
Public Class MyRow
    Public Property Name As String
    Public Property Value As Integer
End Class
```

Set collection of rows to the DataSource fo the DataGridView

```
Private _rows As List(Of MyRow)

Private Sub Form_Load()
  _rows = New List(Of MyRow) From
  {
    New MyRow With { .Name = "AA", .Value = 1 },
    New MyRow With { .Name = "BB", .Value = 2 }
  }

  myDataGridView.DataSource = _rows
End Sub
```

Every time value changed in textbox filter collection and set filtered result to the DataSource

```
Private Sub TextChanged(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles txt.TextChanged
  Dim textbox = DirectCast(sender, TextBox)

  myDataGridView.DataSource = _rows.
    Where(Function(row) row.Name.Contains(textbox.Text)).
    ToList()
End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

i added second datagridview because in one datagridview always zero record found

```
  Sub DATA_TABLE() 
        Dim dt As DataTable = New DataTable
        Dim dr As DataRow
        For COL = 0 To EARSIV_TABLO.ColumnCount - 1
            dt.Columns.Add(EARSIV_TABLO.Columns(COL).HeaderText)
        Next
        For i = 0 To EARSIV_TABLO.RowCount - 1
            dr = dt.NewRow()
            For COL = 0 To EARSIV_TABLO.ColumnCount - 1 
                dr(COL) = EARSIV_TABLO.Rows(i).Cells(COL).Value 
            Next
            dt.Rows.Add(dr)
        Next
        DGV1.DataSource = ""
        DGV1.DataSource = dt
    End Sub
Private Sub TextBox1_TextChanged(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles TextBox1.TextChanged
    TryCast(DGV1.DataSource, DataTable).DefaultView.RowFilter = "UNVAN LIKE '%" & TextBox1.Text & "%'"
End Sub
```